# Can a facebook app create an ad for any post of its managed pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm working on a application that post messages on facebook pages using the `manage_pages, publish_pages` roles.

Now we need to boost some of those post using ads. For that reason, we also ask for the `ads_management, read_ads` roles.

With these roles and the marketing api, we thought that we will be available to create an ad for the page post (with the access token of the page) and using an ad account linked to the app, not to the page (the ad is a reward for posting, so it will be payed by the app).

In our first POC, we get authorization errors when using the access token of the page and the ad account of the app. And this is logic for me: an app cannot allow a page token to use the money on an ad account that does not belong to him/them!

Ok. We changed of approach. Now we use a user token from someone of our organization that have access to the the ad account. Now the marketing api is allowing us to manipulate the account, but this user cannot create ads for the posts of the managed pages because it does not have the Advertiser role on each of those pages!

I think that the problem is that the marketing api does not use application level roles but user roles only ... I'm right?

I'm saying this because our application has all the roles that we need, but of course, our staff don't (facebook users authorize apps, not people from the app's organization).

So, there is a way to use the facebook marketing api using an app that can post and manage ads for that page but that use an ad account that is not related to the page?

Answer (score 0):

The page, for which you want to run ads, will have to add the Ad Account (or respective User account that has access to the Ad Account) as an advertiser to the page. That way, you app will be able to create ads for those pages. Can you confirm that works?